# Ionic Camera: No value accessor for form control with name

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I'm using the **cordova-plugin-camera** plugin in an Ionic app. I managed to make the camera to take a picture and to display it after bit I get this error:

```
No value accessor for form control with name 'photo'
```

I think I might not fully understand how the FormBuilder works. Here is what I got:

register.html

```
<img *ngIf="register_form.controls.photo.value != ''" formControlName="photo" [src]="domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(register_form.controls.photo.value)" />
```

register.ts file

```
ionViewWillLoad() {
  this.register_form = this.formBuilder.group({
    ...
    photo: new FormControl('', Validators.required)
  });
}
...
onTakePicture(){
  ...
  this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {
        const image: FormControl = (<any>this.register_form).controls.photo;
        image.setValue('data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData);
    }, (err) => {
  });
}
```

What is wrong ?

Comment: Can you show place where you create ``FormGroup``? The place where you assign something to ``register_form``

Comment: you need to use avatar instead of photo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`formControlName` can be used only for the control or `directives` which implements `ControlValueAccessor`. Since you are using img which doesn't implement `ControlValueAccessor`, you cannot use here.

Fore more info visit - https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor

Comment: I see! I'll then set an empty input text field that contains the data.